# Constructing a Label for a Form inside a Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code for my `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_with do |form| %>
  <% @electives.each do |elective| %>
    <div>
      <%= elective.name %>
    </div>
    <% elective.courses.each do |course| %>
      <div>
        <%= form.radio_button :elective.id, course.id %>
        <%= form.label %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want to construct the `label` for the radio button, but I don't know how to specify the first argument to it. I am following Rails Guides, and I see that it should have the form: *first argument to `radio_button`* **_** *second argument to `radio_button`*.

So, in my case, it should be `:elective.id_course.id`. But, I don't know how to enter it correctly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the `:value` option, which is designed to target labels for `radio_button` tags:

```
<% elective.courses.each do |course| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.radio_button :elective.id, course.id %>
    <%= form.label :elective.id, course.id, :value: course.id %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

See more on [ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper#label](https://rdoc.info/gems/actionview/6.1.4.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper#label-instance_method)